# Google Sign In fetch extra data

Tags: ios, swift, gidsignin

Can I fetch extra data from Google using GIDSignIn over google+ sign in? Currently I am getting the following data:

```
            let userId = user.userID                  
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken 
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            let email = user.profile.email
            if (user.profile.hasImage) {
                let imageUrl = user.profile.imageURLWithDimension(75)
                print (imageUrl)
            }
```

But i need more info from google account. Can't find any info about it in google tutorial.

Comment: Which additional info you have to get from google account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just checked the [GIDGoogleUser](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_google_user#property-documentation) and those are the only information you can fetch for the user profile(GIDProfileData)!

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
        withError error: NSError!)
```

The signIn method gives you the reference to the GIDGoogleUser with gives you the information you already know how to fetch, and it also gives you the Google user ID, the accessible scopes, host domains and authentication methods. You can check all of this at the [Google Developers Sign In for iOS.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/)

Comment: Yes, I read it, but hoped that it is possible to get more information. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, if you want anything else you will have to use other api's(drive, maps...).